# Usage of spinlocks and semaphore in linux in process and interupt context

Tags: linux-kernel, synchronization, mutex, spinlock, binary-semaphore

What would happen if I use semaphore and mutex locks in interrupt context?
Normally semaphore is used in synchronization mechanism. What would happen if I use this one in an interrupt context?

I am working on a project on gpio pins and when interrupt happens, I have to send one signal in ISR. I am using spinlocks.

What would happen if I use semaphore and mutext in ISR?

Answer (score 1):

Waiting in mutexes and semaphores are implemented using switching current task state to `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE`/`TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE` and similar with futher call to `schedule()`.

Calling `schedule()` with current task state differed from `TASK_RUNNING` leads to switching to another process. And if `current` refers to interrupt context, you will never return back to it, because scheduling can switch only to the *process*.

So, when you lock *contended*(that is, currently locked) semaphore/mutex in interrupt context, you just lost current execution "thread".

If you lock semaphore/mutex which is *uncontended*(currently not locked), execution will be correct except warning in system log about improper semaphore/mutex usage.

Comment: The `current` won't be NULL at any time. So sleeping in the interrupt context will use the thread info of current task to store the info which is able to be scheduled. So the root cause may not be it. Am I right?

Comment: @Arthur It looks like correct answer http://www.quora.com/Why-cant-you-sleep-in-an-interrupt-handler-in-the-Linux-kernel-Is-this-true-of-all-OS-kernels